# How to add a different URL for each iteration in a for loop in Django?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I want to add a new URL link for each iteration in this for loop:

```
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

This is my attempt, which I know is wrong because it is basically giving each entry the same CSS link:

```
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'CSS' %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: What kind of link are you trying to embed in the `href`? Does each `entry` instance have a `.url` property, or are you trying to do something like `some-url/<id>`?

Comment: Hi @JakeTae, yes right now all the entries have associated .html pages that I want to link them to

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to recreate list `entries` into list of tuples `[(entry, url),]` and use it like this:

```html
<ul>
    {% for entry, url in entries %}
        <li><a href = "{% url %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

or just return a separate list of URLs:

```html
<ul>
    {% for entry, url in zip(entries, urls) %}
        <li><a href = "{% url %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```